# Vlookup return a formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I am a teacher at a University. I am trying to make an attendance in excel for one semester. 
I have almost finished but I have hit a problem that I can't find the answer to. I am trying to create a student lookup. Please see picture.

So I thought I would use vlookup taking it from the running total from my students list. However that total is a formula not a value number. I got that total by formula: to add each months total together and place the result there. I can't seem to get vlookup to return a formula just a vault number. The problem is as the semester ins't over that total keeps changing every lesson. So I need vlookup to work with that running total. I have looked for many hours on the net as I thought somebody must have a similae problem but I cant either not find or understand them. If you need the excel file for better understanding I would be happy to share it with you. Thanks in advance

Comment: Put a table together with the working formulae in it and use vlookup to choose the relevant result...

Answer (score 0):

The formula being returned is actually a text string that looks like a formula. You need some workaround to evaluate that formula.
Please share the worksheet so I can understand it better.

Meanwhile this link should be useful for you.

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1104076-can-you-use-vlookup-to-return-a-formula-instead-of-a-value.html